# t490s missing Ethernet (not listed in lspci)

Tags: debian, ethernet, thinkpad

I have t490s laptop which has Wifi and Ethernet.
But when I do `lspci`, there is no Ethernet there, just the Wifi card and also NetworkManager doesn't connect when I plug in rj45 to Ethernet adapter.

I tried various kernels (5.5.0, 5.4.0 - official debian, 5.3.x, 5.0.x) same issue everywhere.

So my question is, is my laptop defective or maybe the ethernet card is somehow disabled in bios or using a hardware switch somewhere?

Comment: did you check the BIOS? or any possible hardware switches? does `dmesg | grep-i ethernet` return anything?